# Using preprocessor conditionals in macro functions with double parentheses

Tags: c, syntax, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Given:

```
#define TRACE(x) do { if (DEBUG) dbg_print x; } while (0)
```

I want:

```
TRACE((
    "Message: %s"
#ifdef MYDEF
    "Additional stuff"
#endif
    , msg));
```

But gives error:

```
error C2121: '#' invalid character : possibly the result of a macro expansion
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ifdef'
error C2121: '#' invalid character : possibly the result of a macro expansion
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I know I can easily resolve this by writing two different `TRACE` calls and using `#ifdef...#else...#endif`, but the above is only a simplified case. My actual use case involve multiple `#ifdef` that controls both the format string and the arguments, so it's not practical write multiple trace calls (e.g. with 3 `ifdef`, I'll need 2^3 = 8 different calls to take care of all the possible combinations). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Should be `dbg_print(x)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, that's not what he's doing (see the call, he passes parentheses for the function call there).

Comment: It's simply not possible.

Comment: @Axalo It's not portable, but it is possible. There is also a workaround to non-portability.

Comment: Can you convert your TRACE() macro to a static inline function ?

Comment: @nos: To do that, my compiler must be able to handle variable argument list, and I could have used `#define TRACE(...) do { if (DEBUG) dbg_print(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)`, which would eliminate the double parentheses and therefore the problem altogether. Another limitation is that `TRACE` has been used extensively throughout the legacy code I'm working on, so changing it is not very practical too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some compilers will compile your code through compiler extension, but it is not portable. You can work around this issue by conditionally defining another macro, and using its result in a call of `TRACE`, like this:

```
#ifdef MYDEF
#define IF_MY(x,y) x y
#else
#define IF_MY(x,y) x
#endif
```

Now you can write your `TRACE` as follows:

```
TRACE((IF_MY("Message: %s", "Additional stuff"), msg));
```

[Demo #1.](http://ideone.com/61EGmh)

> it seems like it will run into scalability issues.

That impression is incorrect. You can scale this approach quite easily to as many variables as you wish without running into combinatorial explosion. Here is an example of adding a second variable:

```
#ifdef YOURDEF
#define IF_MY_YOUR(x,y,z) IF_MY(x,y) z
#else
#define IF_MY_YOUR(x,y,z) IF_MY(x,y)
#endif
```

Now you can use the combined macro in your `TRACE`:

```
TRACE((IF_MY_YOUR("Message: %s", "Additional stuff", "More stuff"), msg));
```

[Demo #2 - Both `MYDEF` and `YOURDEF` are defined](http://ideone.com/uW7DDq)

[Demo #2 - Only `YOURDEF` is defined](http://ideone.com/x7NZzZ)

[Demo #2 - Only `MYDEF` is defined](http://ideone.com/LGtqvD)

[Demo #2 - Neither `MYDEF` or `YOURDEF` is defined](http://ideone.com/Y10O3O)

> What if I have additional arguments that are to be controlled by #define too?

Do the same thing for parameters, with commas in between `x` and `y` parts. The call of `TRACE` would look like this:

```
TRACE((
    IF_MY_YOUR_FMT("Message: %s", "Additional %s stuff", "More %s stuff")
,   IF_MY_YOUR_ARG(msg1, msg2, msg3)
));
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but it seems like it will run into scalability issues. Your example only handles 1 "additional stuff". What if I have 3, each to be controlled by a different `#define` flag? Also, this only handles the format string. What if I have additional arguments that are to be controlled by `#define` too?

Comment: Wait, `IF_MY_YOUR` allows for the "y z", "y" and ""(neither) case. How about the "z" case?

Comment: @wmjdgla You are right, I need to put `IF_MY` on both branches. See the edit and the four demos.